# How to programmatically read the contents of InfoPath form?

Tags: 2010, infopath, object-model

I have form with data in repeating table. I need to use the object model to read the contents and display it on a webpart. Is it possible? Can any of you help me?

Answer (score 1):

InfoPath for is XML file, so reading it can be done with basic XML methods within the web part.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968809/programatically-edit-infopath-form-fields) contains example code.